# C++ enforce passing of object to certain scope

Tags: c++

I want to design a system with a `Sink` and a `Source` type.

I want to create a `Token` that is created by the `Source` and must be passed to a `Sink`.

Creating an object within a certain scope can be enforced by a `friend` declaration. However, I wonder how I can enforce that the object is passed to a `Sink`.

Since C++ does not offer destructive moves, a moved-from object is still valid and will be destructed in its scope. So, it is not possible to chain move operations to move the object from one point to another and declare the destructor private.

```
class Sink;
class Source;

class Token{
  friend class Source;
  friend class Sink;
private:
  Token() = default;
  ~Token() = default;
};
```

Is it possible to design a class for which the compiler is able to check that it was moved to a certain scope?

As of now, I am forced to use a compiler that does not offer guaranteed copy elision.

Comment: No, the compiler can't check that in the general case.  Consider `Token t = source.produce(); if (rand() % 2) { sink.process(std::move(t)); }`.  There is no way to tell at compile time if `t` will be processed by `sink`.

Comment: Move in c++ IS destructive, at least it should be considered destructive to the original object (although it is up to the implementer of the move operation if it is truly destructive). If you believe otherwise, then you are implementing it incorrectly. You CAN chain moves together to move an object around and invalidate the original objects. If you are creating those objects yourself, then you must implement a mechanism to invalidate them. The compiler has no need to know this, as this is enforcement left up to implementation. Ultimately you probably need to refactor your design and approach

Comment: What's the real goal here, OP?  To ensure that you don't try to use a moved-from object?  If so, I'm afraid you're out of luck.  `assert (!moved_from)` in the relevant methods is perhaps your best bet.

Comment: @PaulSanders the goal is that a created Token should be consumed by a Sink. I want to ensure that a user gets notified about a valid Token that is destructed outside of a Sink

Comment: @deviantgeek move is not defined as destructive. My point is that the destructor is called even if the object was moved from. So it is in general not possible to declare the destructor private to achive my goal. In c++17 we have guaranteed copy elision, so i could declare the destructor private and enforce a chain of Returns to the Sink.

Comment: @MilesBudnek that is a good example for a case where it is known that the token might not be moved from. So an ideal behaviour would be that this code won't even compile.

Comment: Would you be happy with runtime safeguards?  As @MilesBudnek pointed out it won't be possible at compile time.

Comment: @joergbrech not really. Not possible would be also an answer. But i would need some facts for that. Every information necessary is available at compile time. But it might be that there is no way in c++ to express that information.